# Deploying Windows 10 anniversary through WSUS

Tags: wsus, windows-10

Can someone tell me how to get the Windows 10 anniversary update (build 1607) into WSUS correctly?

I tried adding the upgrades classification and it pulled in a bunch of build 1607 packages. I approved "Feature update to Windows 10 Pro, version 1607, en-us". I am using my computer to test which is on build 1511, the update that was approved doesn't show any computers needing the update even after downloading the files needed.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction of getting this working?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your WSUS server is configured, you may first need KB3159706.

Also see: http://m.windowsitpro.com/windows-10/windows-10-anniversary-update-arrive-wsus-and-configmgr-users-august-16

> The Windows Team has released update KB3159706 that enables the
>   provisioning of decryption keys in WSUS for Windows Server 2012 and
>   2012 R2. This update is necessary for WSUS to be able to natively
>   decrypt the encrypted Windows 10 Anniversary Update packages, and any
>   subsequent Windows 10 feature upgrades.  Additionally, the 1606 update
>   for the current branch of Configuration Manger contains new client
>   support that allows these types of packages to install correctly using
>   the Configuration Manager Windows 10 servicing feature.

Comment: Did microsoft start encrypting updates?

Comment: I do have that update installed along with the manual steps needed afterward

Comment: @FrankThornton Given that they are now allowing Windows Updates to be shared peer-to-peer, it is logical that they would start encrypting them.